# Why in Windows 7 do I see the Data & Time inverse and in Windows XP it is fine?

Tags: windows-7, c#

Why in Windows 7 do I see the Data & Time in [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) inverse and in Windows XP it is fine?  (the region and language are the same)

For example:

```
Win7:  2010/12/31  -  51:09

XP  :  31/12/2010  -  09:51
```

Comment: Hello. You've been a member of StackOverflow for a year and have a high reputation score, so you're not exactly new here. What makes you think this is a programming related question?

Comment: DataTimePicker, I guess.

Comment: Because Win7 has given you a sensible date format? (Unfortunately it has failed on the time :-(.) YYYY-MM-DD is the international standard format, and sorts textually with string comparisons.

Comment: I totally prefer the Y-M-D format, sure. I have no idea why time is reversed, are you saying it's the default? Makes no sense to me...

Comment: @Gold: You could probably avoid any confusion about this being programming related if you included the line of code that produces those results.

Answer (score 4):

You likely messed with the custom region settings. For instance, setting mm:hh instead of hh:mm for time display. The custom settings override the default regional settings.

The settings are used system-wide - in DataTime picker controls as well. If you want to use a certain, fixed format, you can simply set it on the picker.